# .net mvc, set role for user come from outlook

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

My project have two auth type. One is built-in asp.net membership and one from outlook. Main user (Asp.net membership) can choose login to their outlook account to do some task like create appointment in calendar. How we add more role like "OutlookUser" for user currently logged into their outlook account.

Comment: by `outlook account` do you mean Active directory authentication?

Comment: login to Microsoft Graph API